# How to read the background color with exceljs?

Tags: node.js, exceljs

I'm reading an Excel Workbook in a node.js application (TestCafe) with exceljs. I know how to retrieve the value of an Excel cell:
`worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell( colName ).value`
But I don't know how to retrieve the background color of this cell. I checked the exceljs documentation on Github, but couldn't see any hint on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer by trying:
`worksheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(colName).fill.bgColor.argb;`